# PyQt5: How to center QDialog inside centralwidget of QMainWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have a QMainWindow like this:[image]

In the top of the window there is title bar (default windows behavior) with the title the program icon and the minimize, maximize and close buttons.
After there is a menubar, and under it there is a toolbar.
Then there is the main centralwidget (which has only a stackedwidget as child widget).
And in the bottom of the page there is the statusbar.

When i open a new QDialog using .exec() method i want:

1. QDialog size to be 0.98*centralwidget_size
2. QDialog to be centered so the center of QDialog to be the center a centralwidget.
3. Make 2. responsive if it's possible (I mean the QDialog's rect() to be changed on QMainWindow rect() change).

I tried many methods with no luck.

```py
            title_bar_height = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_TitleBarHeight)
            central_widget_width = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameSize().width())
            central_widget_height = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameSize().height())
            self.setFixedSize(int(0.95*central_widget_width),int(1.0*(central_widget_height-title_bar_height)))

            central_widget_top_x = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().x())
            central_widget_top_y = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().y())
            central_widget_width = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().width())
            central_widget_height = int(self.main_self.ui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().height())

            qdialog_width = self.frameGeometry().width()
            qdialog_height = self.frameGeometry().height()
            print(central_widget_top_y)#->75
            qdialog_new_x = central_widget_top_x + (central_widget_width-qdialog_width)/2
            qdialog_new_y = central_widget_top_y + (central_widget_height-qdialog_height)/2
            self.move(int(qdialog_new_x),int(qdialog_new_y))
            print(self.frameGeometry().y()) #->75
```

[image]

The size is correct, but the x,y aren't.

Comment: *What* did you try and why they didn't work? As usual, a [mre] would help, you should know that. Point 3 is also unclear, so try to explain it better.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know 100% how that works but using:

```py
self.move(self.main_self.MainWindow.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(int(qdialog_new_x),int(qdialog_new_y))))
```

set the position to the right coordinates.